# H1:before trouble involving image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to make a css headline that looks like this[image: Reference]

I have the triangle as a png with transparency, but I haven't really used pseudo elements before, so if anyone could help that would be awesome.

So far I've got this:

```
h1 {text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: 600; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h1:before {
content: url( "../images/triangle.png" ) ;
margin-right: -50px;}
```

This places the text correctly horizontally, but I can't find a way to place the text correctly vertically

Comment: Add fiddle so we can help you resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below css and manage this via position:

```
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative
}
h1:before {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url( "../images/triangle.png" );
    right: -50px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/obmwncd4/

To add background image, remove all the border in `h1:before`, and add width and height of the image

Answer (score 0):

so you want to make the text vertical ?
try this

```
.vertical-text {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huyyrc3p/2/)**

```
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    line-height:80px;
    text-indent:20px;
}
h1:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    /* to be below the parent element */
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>fddfgfdg</h1>
```